# YAML file for cronjob in openshift

Tags: cron, openshift, openshift-origin, persistent-volumes

So I was working on small project and I learned about cronjobs in openshift. From this https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html#creating-a-cronjob

I learned how to write the yaml file. But I am confused about what to mention in container field and how to associate PV to cron job.

I am working with Persistent volume to clear a log file from PV at regular interval through cron job.

Can anyone help me with core understanding of execution of cron job and how do I mention in yaml file for  command to delete file inside PV for a pod which has PV mounted to it.